# How to call a function after all images in queue gets uploaded in swfupload

Tags: php, jquery, swfupload

I m using this code and i want to call a function after all images in queue gets uploaded.

```
$(function(){
    $('#swfupload-control').swfupload({
        upload_url: "upload.php",
        file_post_name: 'uploadfile',
        file_size_limit : "20000",
        file_types : "*.jpg;*.png;*.gif",
        file_types_description : "Image files",
        file_upload_limit :500,
        flash_url : "js/swfupload/swfupload.swf",
        button_image_url : 'js/swfupload/wdp_buttons_upload_114x29.png',
        button_width : 114,
        button_height : 29,
        button_placeholder : $('#button')[0],
        debug: false
    })
        .bind('fileQueued', function(event, file){
            var listitem=''+
                'File: '+file.name+' ('+Math.round(file.size/20000)+' KB) '+
                ''+
                'Pending'+
                ' '+
                '';
            $('#log').append(listitem);
            $('li#'+file.id+' .cancel').bind('click', function(){
                var swfu = $.swfupload.getInstance('#swfupload-control');
                swfu.cancelUpload(file.id);
                $('li#'+file.id).slideUp('fast');
            });
            // start the upload since it's queued
            $(this).swfupload('startUpload');
        })
        .bind('fileQueueError', function(event, file, errorCode, message){
            alert('Size of the file '+file.name+' is greater than limit');
        })
        .bind('fileDialogComplete', function(event, numFilesSelected, numFilesQueued){
            $('#queuestatus').text('Files Selected: '+numFilesSelected+' / Queued Files: '+numFilesQueued);
        })
        .bind('uploadStart', function(event, file){
            $('#log li#'+file.id).find('p.status').text('Uploading...');
            $('#log li#'+file.id).find('span.progressvalue').text('0%');
            $('#log li#'+file.id).find('span.cancel').hide();
        })
        .bind('uploadProgress', function(event, file, bytesLoaded){
            //Show Progress
            var percentage=Math.round((bytesLoaded/file.size)*100);
            $('#log li#'+file.id).find('div.progress').css('width', percentage+'%');
            $('#log li#'+file.id).find('span.progressvalue').text(percentage+'%');
        })
        .bind('uploadSuccess', function(event, file, serverData){
            var item=$('#log li#'+file.id);
            item.find('div.progress').css('width', '100%');
            item.find('span.progressvalue').text('100%');
            var pathtofile='/'+file.name+'" target="_blank" >view »';
            item.addClass('success').find('p.status').html('');
        })
        .bind('uploadComplete', function(event, file){
            // upload has completed, try the next one in the queue
            $(this).swfupload('startUpload');

        })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a plugin like [uplodify](http://www.uploadify.com/)

It provides a call back function after uploading one or more images. You can find the relevant examples in their documentation.

Comment: looks like his uploader does this as well

Comment: @Andy you are probably write, I am at work so I didn't go through the code :) just shared the way I treated the problem.

Answer (score 0):

get the count of the files you upload and in the uploadComplete event handler keep track of how many times it's called and check if it equals the count.

Answer (score 0):

add handler:

```
upload_complete_handler     : uploadComplete
```

and in handlers.js at the end of function add what code you like:

```
function uploadComplete(file) {
    try {
        /*  I want the next upload to continue automatically so I'll call startUpload here */
        if (this.getStats().files_queued === 0) {
            document.getElementById(this.customSettings.cancelButtonId).disabled = true;
        } else {    
            this.startUpload();
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        this.debug(ex);
    }

    // do what you want HERE!
}
```